# Trying to collect API data and send to local mysql

Tags: python, mysql, api

I cannot get this script that i created to work.
it needs to collect API data (returns a JSON)
and i want to save specific data to MYSQL

played around with the code and didnt get it to work...
various "expected an indented block" errors

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import re
import MySQLdb
import json

data = requests.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

HOST = "localhost"
USER = "root"
PASSWD = "user"
DATABASE = "something"

def store_data(articles, source, auther, title, description, url, timestamp, content):
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host = HOST, user = USER, passwd = PASSWD, db = DATABASE, charset = "utf8")
cursor = db.cursor()
insert_query = MySQLdb.escape_string("INSERT INTO table (articles, source, auther, title, description, url, timestamp, content) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
cursor.execute(insert_query, (articles, source, auther, title, description, url, timestamp, content))
db.commit()
cursor.close()
db.close()
return

        # db = MySQLdb.connect(host = HOST, user = USER, passwd = PASSWD, db = DATABASE, charset = "utf8")# cursor = db.cursor()

def on_data(self, data): #This is the meat of the script...it connects to your mongoDB and stores the tweet
try:
datajson = json.loads(data) #  grab the wanted data from the Tweet
articles = datajson['articles']
source = datajson['articles']['source']['name']
auther = datajson['articles']['auther']
title = datajson['articles']['title']
description = datajson['articles']['description']
url = datajson['articles']['url']
timestamp = parser.parse(datajson['articles']['publishedAt'])
content = datajson['articles']['content']

# insert the data into the MySQL database
store_data(articles, source, auther, title, description, url, timestamp, content)
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

i expect the output to be stored into a mysql table... but i get error while trying to run the script.
Also i need to make it run endlessly untill ill kill the process/session....

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import MySQLdb
from dateutil import parser

HOST = "localhost"
USER = "root"
PASSWD = "ssss!"
DATABASE = "sss"

def store_data(articles):
    db=MySQLdb.connect(host=HOST, user=USER, passwd=PASSWD, db=DATABASE, charset="utf8")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    insert_query = MySQLdb.escape_string("INSERT INTO usa_news (articles) VALUES (%s)")
    cursor.execute(insert_query, (articles,))
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    return


# api-endpoint
URL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/sources?apiKey=ssssssssss"


# API given here
country = "us"


# defining a params dict for the parameters to be sent to the API
PARAMS = {'country':country}

# sending get request and saving the response as response object
r = requests.get(url = URL, params= PARAMS)

# extracting data in json format
data = r.json()

# extracting latitude, longitude and formatted address
# of the first matching location
articles = data['sources'][0]['id']

# printing the output
print("article name:%s"
      %(articles))

#insert the data into the MySQL database
store_data(articles)
```

Finally made it work!

Comment: the only thing now is that i only get the first result in from the API, and not all of them:(

Comment: To get all the results, you could loop through `for i in range(len(data['sources'])): print(data['sources'][i]['id'])`

Answer (score 0):

Your indents are all messed up, Python relies on indents. Didn't look at the code itself so it might still be bugged, but fixed the indents:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import re
import MySQLdb
import json

HOST = "localhost"
USER = "root"
PASSWD = "user"
DATABASE = "something"

def store_data(articles, source, auther, title, description, url, timestamp, content):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host = HOST, user = USER, passwd = PASSWD, db = DATABASE, charset = "utf8")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    insert_query = MySQLdb.escape_string("INSERT INTO table (articles, source, auther, title, description, url, timestamp, content) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
    cursor.execute(insert_query, (articles, source, auther, title, description, url, timestamp, content))
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    return

        # db = MySQLdb.connect(host = HOST, user = USER, passwd = PASSWD, db = DATABASE, charset = "utf8")# cursor = db.cursor()

def on_data(data): #This is the meat of the script...it connects to your mongoDB and stores the tweet
    try:
        datajson = json.loads(data) #  grab the wanted data from the Tweet
        articles = datajson['articles']
        source = datajson['articles']['source']['name']
        auther = datajson['articles']['auther']
        title = datajson['articles']['title']
        description = datajson['articles']['description']
        url = datajson['articles']['url']
        timestamp = parser.parse(datajson['articles']['publishedAt'])
        content = datajson['articles']['content']

        # insert the data into the MySQL database
        store_data(articles, source, auther, title, description, url, timestamp, content)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = requests.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    on_data(data)
```

**Updated to reflect changes suggested in comments**

Comment: the arrangement helped- but would appreciate if someone can checkout the code... something aint right

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide any errors you're getting

Comment: Thats the thing its running but i dont have any error - but data is not going in the DB

Comment: Is this your entire script? If so, you're never calling the `on_data()` function which is why nothing happens. At the bottom of your file, add this: `on_data(data)` without any indents. Also, remove the `self` parameter in the `on_data()` definition, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: I editted my answer a bit to reflect the changes I suggested and moved your data collection and calling of function in a main-check

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - however, i am calling the on_data(data) functions - its the last row....

Comment: Unless I need new glasses, I only see you call store_data from within on_data

Comment: i used your script after you organized the spaces. at the bottom the last row there is on_data(data)

Comment: Yeah I added that an hour ago... it wasn't in the version posted yesterday.

Comment: Still - i dont get any indications and the data is not in ... :(

Comment: ok so i have changed the script - and now i get an indication that i cut the json correctly because of the Print function ... any idea why its not inserting to the DB ?

Comment: You had added 2 answes yourself now, with different versions of your code. Could you edit your initial question to reflect all of your code as you have it right now and explain what is and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import MySQLdb
from dateutil import parser

HOST = "localhost"
USER = "root"
PASSWD = "xxxxx"
DATABASE = "xxxxx"



# api-endpoint
URL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/sources?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"


# API given here
country = "us"


# defining a params dict for the parameters to be sent to the API
PARAMS = {'country':country}

# sending get request and saving the response as response object
r = requests.get(url = URL, params= PARAMS)

# extracting data in json format
data = r.json()

# extracting latitude, longitude and formatted address
# of the first matching location
articles = data['sources'][0]['id']

# printing the output
print("article name:%s"
      %(articles))


def store_data(articles):
    db=MySQLdb.connect(host=HOST, user=USER, passwd=PASSWD, db=DATABASE, charset="utf8")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    insert_query = MySQLdb.escape_string("INSERT INTO xxxxx (articles) VALUES (%s)")
    cursor.execute(insert_query, (articles))
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    return


#insert the data into the MySQL database
    store_data(articles)
```